# jQuery .html() возвращает DOM объект

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Строчка:

```
jQuery(function(){ jQuery('.call_phone_1').html('sample');  });
```

должна подменить хтмл элемента с классом `call_phone_1` на `sample`, однако вместо этого я получаю в консоли `[#document]`. Почему такое происходит? Если было бы просто:

```
jQuery('.call_phone_1').html('sample');
```

то оно бы сработало, но так как этот скрипт приходит со стороннего ресурса, я не могу его изменить. Как заставить код работать?(на данный момент он не подменяет)
Версия : jquery-1.9.1.min.js CMS PHPshop.

Comment: Версии jQuery, браузера, пример на jsfiddle?

Comment: обновил. на jsfiddle он сработает. но вот на данном сайте почему-то нет.

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка возникает если по селектору ничего не найдено, возможно вы вызываете функцию раньше, чем элемент появится в DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Он и должен возвращать jQuery-коллекцию. jQuery поддерживает так называемый Fluent Interface - все вызовы методов, которые не должны возвращать информацию, возвращают тот объект, на котором были вызваны. Это позволяет делать цепочки вызовов:

```
$('div:last').html('whateva').css('color', 'red').width(200);
```

Если вам возвращается непустая коллекция - значит, `html()` выполнился на этой коллекции. Скорее всего, вы по тем или иным причианм не можете этого отследить (изменились не те элементы, на которые вы смотрите, например).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё стало понятно. К сожалению, чтобы поставить плюс нужна репутация, которой у меня нет:) Да, действительно, строчка срабатывает, но видимо не в то время. Продолжаю копать теперь уже в этом направлении.

Answer (score 0):

Какая разница, что он возвращает, если замена делается?

Все jQuery-методы при вызове для присваивания возвращают исходный набор.

Comment: К сожалению, замена-то не делается.

Answer (score 0):

а не вызывается ли данная функция перед отрисовкой самого элемента? Всмысле попробуйте под перенести пере закрывающим тегом body

Comment: похоже что так.

Comment: `jQuery(function(){ jQuery('.call_phone_1').html('sample');  });` - этот вариант вызывает функцию после загрузки документа. Изменение места внутри разметки ничего не изменит.

Comment: А что именно приходит со стороннего сервера? Не может быть такого, что элемент отрисовывается каким-нибудь другим скриптом, а происходит это уже после вызова вашей функциии.. Это я о том что может элемент и рисуется скриптом, который приходит с другого сервера